# Internet Security on Super User

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request, off-topic

While the topic of **Internet security** is not listed in what should be asked about, it is also not listed as being off-topic.

I think Internet security is worth paying attention to. Recently I posted [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1272628/why-do-people-expend-signifcant-effort-on-pirating-the-works-of-others-for-free?noredirect=1#comment1876705_1272628) question on Super User and it is [on hold] for being off-topic.  That's fair enough.

**My question:** Why are moderators avoiding such an important topic?
Why it should not be discussed on Super User?

**I think** this topic should be added in this community or a new Stack Exchange community should be started (this latter idea does not seems worth of doing).

Comment: For one, an [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com) StackExchange does already exist, so that answers part of your suggestion.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with computers and everything  to do with people. Your question doesn't even have anything to do with the internet or security, it is purely about the motivations and reasons people do certain things such as piracy or, since your edit, write open source software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, internet security, in the context of your computer is quite often on topic.

Lets talk about *your* question first - Its really not about computers. Its about people, and the mindsets behind piracy.

We have a [security](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/security) tag and a malware/security focused [community-faq](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit) post. Security when its about a security and computers is perfectly fine (all other factors being taken into account.